# All content overlaps in a slide

Tags: html, css, slick.js

All content overlaps in a slide and when i hit the second dot to switch to the 2nd slide , is not nothing because all of them in the first slide. 
i'm use slick so that file js of it is very long and i don'n know where the code about slide.[this is image where the problem i said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2MW.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to hide items that go out of each slide by adding `overflow: hidden`; on your `.slide` class.

Comment: Thank you! i did it before i'm post but the problem is not there and i solved it =)) <#